# Copy javascript made images to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, clipboard

Is there today with HTML5 a way to copy to clipboard, without browser plugins (and so without Flash nor java) nor short-term hacks, an image built in a canvas ?

The copy to clipboard would be initiated by javascript but having user confirmation or a dialog isn't a problem.

Solutions which don't work in Windows and Linux, or which don't work at least in Chrome and Firefox are without interest to me.

Ideally I would prefer a solution that doesn't impose to display the image (which is built in memory with `document.createElement('canvas')`) but that's not an absolute requirement.

Comment: Try here: http://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/accessing-the-system-clipboard-with-javascript/

Comment: Thanks but this is might not be up to date. In fact I know this wasn't possible a few months ago but I'm wondering if there are new solutions (especially with the new clipboard API ( http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/ ) whose possibilities are somewhat obscure to me).

Comment: That's API is **too new** (and unstable) to be used...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the [Clipboard API](http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) is the only specification in this area. I've never used it and don't know how widely it's supported, but I suspect not widely. According to [this quick and dirty test](http://jsbin.com/exibid), the current versions of Chrome and Firefox fire the `copy` event. I believe the user has to initiate the copy (e.g., you say "press Ctrl+C to copy").

IE makes [`window.clipboardData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) available, but as far as I know you're limited to text and URLs.

So sadly, I think this is one of those answers that's basically: No, not yet.

Comment: Hi, can you please make an example where the clipboard is set (lets say to "Hello, world")? I can't figure it out from the spec. And its kinda silly to open a new question just for that.